# Issue Initializing Double Stacked linked lists in C

Tags: c

I am coding a data structure involving a set of two linked lists, stacked on top of each other. When trying to initialize the set in my test harness, I get a segmentation error. I've commented out all value setters to test to see if I could figure out the error myself, but I could not.

Prototype for init method:

Test Harness:

```
int
main( )
{
  list the_list;
  int used = 0;
  int values[MAX_VALUES];
  char input[LINE_LEN];
  char command;
  int argument;
  int num_found;
  bool result;
  set_t lower;
  set_t upper;
  the_list->lower = lower;
  the_list->upper = upper;

 input[0] = '\0';
  input[LINE_LEN-1] = '\0';

  fgets( input, LINE_LEN, stdin );
  while (*input != 'q') {
    num_found = sscanf( input, "%c %d", &command, &argument );

    if (num_found > 0) {
      switch (command) {
        case 'i':
          printf ("Request to initialize the set\n");
          if (num_found == 1) {
            result = set_init( &the_list );
          } else {
            result = set_init( NULL );
          }
          printf ("Returned as %d\n", result);
          break;


                                                        34,0-1         8%
```

Init method:

```
bool
set_init( list *the_list )
{
  bool initialized = false;
  if (the_list !=NULL ) {
    /* We have space to initialize. */

    the_list->lower->set_size = 0;
   /* the_list->lower->head = NULL;
    the_list->lower->tail = NULL;
    the_list->lower->set_level = 1;
    the_list->lower->ready = true;
    the_list->upper->set_size = 0;
    the_list->upper->head = NULL;
    the_list->upper->tail = NULL;
    the_list->upper->set_level = 2;
    the_list->upper->ready = true;*/
    initialized = true;
    }
  return initialized;
  }
```

Also my struct definitions for my set, linked list, and node structs:

```
typedef struct _set_node_t {
        test_type_t *data;
        struct _set_node_t *next;
        struct _set_node_t *below;
} set_node_t;

/* the set itself keeps track of the head and the tail of the linked list */
typedef struct {

        int set_size;
        bool ready;
        set_node_t *head;
        set_node_t *tail;
        int set_level;
} set_t;

typedef struct {
        set_t *lower;
        set_t *upper;
}list;
```

Comment: Did you mean `if (i == 1 )`?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that could be crashing here is this line:

```
the_list->lower->set_size = 0;
```

Either the_list or the_list->lower must be uninitialized or NULL or be pointing to invalid or inaccessible memory.

Edit: Yeah this line will crash because you don't initialize the_list.lower:

```
result = set_init( &the_list );
```

And this line will crash because you're passing NULL:

```
result = set_init( NULL );
```

Comment: how exactly would I fixed this? I tried setting the whole set, and the lower and upper linked lists to null but it still sent a segmentation fault

Comment: Your need to provide the code that calls into set_init()

Comment: ok edit and  post the prototype and the test harness where set_init() is called

Comment: @SamBarefoot If you dereference a null pointer, you will get a segmentation fault.

Comment: This will probably be the dumbest question possible, but how would I initialize the linked lists lower and upper when they are pointers to linked lists?

Comment: Yea... I think you're missing some fundamental understanding here.  You need to actually allocate the objects first, then you can assign the objects to those members.  Something like: `the_list.lower = (set_t*)malloc(sizeof(set_t));`

Make sure to free the memory too at some point.

Comment: Ok, this has everything working. So for next time, when defining user created objects, I must manually allocate space. Sorry I'm used to java so this is fairly new to me. Finally, is major functional difference between using "." and "->" when referring to members of a struct. From what I understand you are suppose to use "->" when the member is a pointer

Comment: Yeah when you allocate an object on the stack you can access the members with . but if you have a pointer to a dynamically allocated object you need to use ->

Comment: But no, to clarify, there is no major functional difference between . and ->, they're just syntax for the same thing.  Instead of using -> you could even do `(*pointer).` which effectively is the same thing.